# No values in dropdown lists with Thymeleaf and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-4

I have a similar issue on my drop down list not showing any values. Like
the solution: dropdown lists with Thymeleaf and SpringBoot No data showing
in dropdown list.   If I look in the IE debugger I can see my list for the
dropdown, but the dropdown won't display my list to pick from. 
The HTML snippet is here:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> 
         <select th:field="*{savings_type}" name="savings_type_id" 
            id="savings_type_id" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Savings Type</option>
            <option th:each="dropDownItem : ${leanTypesList}"
                    th:value="${dropDownItem.lt_id}"
                    th:text="${dropDownItem.lt_name}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code here:
 
My Model leanDeatil.java - data populating Savings_Type field
This is value is going too.

```
@Entity

@Table(name="lean_detail")

public class LeanDetail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    //@Column (name="LEANDETAIL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column (name="SAVINGS_TYPE")
    private int savings_type;   

    @Column (name="SAVING_AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal saving_amount;

    @Column (name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column (nullable=true, name="IMPROVEMENT_DESC")
    private String improvement_desc;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SAVINGS_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "lt_id",
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LeanTypes leanTypes;

    public LeanDetail(){}

    public LeanDetail(String title,int savings_type, BigDecimal saving_amount,
        String improvement_desc {
     super();

     this.title = title;
     this.savings_type = savings_type;
     this.saving_amount = saving_amount;
     this.improvement_desc = improvement_desc;

  }
  getters and setters....
```

My Model leanTypes.java data coming from

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lean_types")
public class LeanTypes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="LT_ID")
    private int lt_id;

    @Column (name="LT_NAME")
    private String lt_name;

    @Column (name="LT_DESC")
    private String lt_desc;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="LT_ACTV")
    private boolean lt_actv;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="leanTypes", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<LeanDetail> leanDetail = new ArrayList<LeanDetail>();

    public LeanTypes(){}

    public LeanTypes(int lt_id, String lt_name, String lt_desc, Boolean lt_actv) {
        super();
        this.lt_id = lt_id;
        this.lt_name = lt_name;
        this.lt_desc = lt_desc;
        this.lt_actv = lt_actv;
    }

    getters and setters....
}
```

From my Controller LeanDetail.java

```
@GetMapping("/update-leanDetail")
public String updateLeanDetail(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest
     request){  
   request.setAttribute("leanTypesList", leanTypesService.findAll());
   request.setAttribute("leanDetail", leanDetailService.findLeanDetail
     (id));
   request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_UPDATE");
   return "leanDetail";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I don't readily see the issue in your HTML - perhaps try removing all the classes in the HTML to make sure nothing is hiding it.  Also, it's best practice to use `model.addAttribute("var" var);` instead of `request.setAttribute("var", var);`  Finally, does your `<form>` tag have something like `th:object="${leanDetail}"`?

Comment: And also 1) print the value of `leanTypesService.findAll()` on the server-side and 2) post a screenshot of what you see in your debugger/browser to make things clear

Comment: I think its an issue with thyme-leaf I did both your recommendations to no avail.   In the debugger in IE and Edge I was able to see the list to pick from but the list would not display.   I was finally able to get it to work just JSTL below is the code snippet:

Comment: <select name="savetype" roleId="savetype" id="savetype"" class="form-control selectpicker"> 
 <option value="">Select Savings Type</option>
 <c:forEach items="${leanTypesMap}" var="leanType">
     <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${leanType.value eq leanDetail.leanTypes.lt_name}">
   <option value= "${leanType.key}" selected="true">${leanType.value}</option>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     <option value="${leanType.key}">${leanType.value}</option>
  </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
   </c:forEach>
</select>

Comment: Why do you have both `th:field="*{savings_type}"` and  `name="savings_type_id"` ?